# align a list by date in ascending order using OrderBy

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have this query that fetches me some items that have a registered request, I created a class to store the item and request data in strings, and I need to sort them by the date of creation from the latest to the oldest.

```
var Items = await this.ItemsRepository.GetAllAsync(expression);

            var report = new List<RegisteredOrders>();
            foreach (var item in Items)
            {
               var request = await this.RequestRepository.GetOneAsync(x => !x.Deleted && x.Id                            == item.requestId);
              
               report.Add (new RegisteredRequest
                   (
                     requestDate: request.CreatedAt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                     requestNum: request.RequestCode,
                     itemDate: item.CreatedAt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                     itemNum: item.ItemCode
                   ));
            }
            var orderReport = report.OrderBy(x => x.requestDate).ThenBy(x => x.itemDate);
            return orderReport.ToList();
```

tried to use OrderBy but it's not working, What's happening?

Comment: Because `requestData`is a string, It will sort alphabetically. Better store it as `DateTime`

Comment: seems your `requestDate` is a string in the format of `dd/MM/YYYY`, So obviously `01/02/2022` is less than `31/01/2022` ... Either store your `requestDate` really as a date, or choose a sortable string representation of the date `YYYY-MM-dd`

Comment: @Klaus Gütter
 I can't instantiate dateTime in the RegisteredRequest class because it needs string values for other uses. and also the date needs to be in "dd/MM/yyyy"

Comment: `var orderReport = report.OrderBy(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.requestDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ThenBy(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.itemDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));`
would sort it (with miserable performance). The right way to solve it would be using DateTime properties rather then strings, as already mentioned by the other commentators.

Comment: @lidqy Worked! i used report.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.requestDate). Date) and ordered correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no way to change the variables within the RegisteredRequest class. So I had to convert the strings to date time so I could use OrderBy as @lidqy said and it worked.

```
var orderReport = report.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.requestDate).Date).ThenBy(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.itemDate).Date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control over the RegisteredRequest Class?  My approach would be to keep the property you assign to as DateTime and if you really want to be able to access it as a string then make another property that only has a get accessor that is the tostring of the datetime in the format you want.

You could then sort by the DateTime property that you set, but use the formatted date property in whatever report you're displaying.